# Orbeon Forms Field Positions

Tags: orbeon

Is there a way to capture and store the X and Y coordinates of a field location on a generated PDF? Trying to send dynamic signature field locations to an electronic signature application and stumped on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry there is no way to do this at this point.